# How to convert custom object to QVariant

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class called `Segment` which contains a few QStrings and is meant to be subclassed.

I created a `std::list` of `Segment` objects and would like to convert that list into a QVariantList. But this begins with converting my individual `Segment` objects into QVariant objects, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Segment);.